# How can I put the Image in the background of a Form in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, background, swiftui-form

I'm currently working on an app and I wonder how to insert an image as a background of a `Form` in SwiftUI.

I have already tried this:

```swift
.onAppear {
   UITableView.appearance().backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Background"))  
}
```

First, it seemed to work, but when I pressed one of the multiple NavigationLinks that has the Form, the App crashes.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *clear* both the `UITableView` and the `UITableViewCell` appearance:

```
UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

Then, you can change the `background` as you wish:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    init() {
        UITableView.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Text("Item!")
                .listRowBackground(Color.clear)
        }
        .background(
            Image("Background")
        )
    }
}
```

(You also need `.listRowBackground` if you want to change the *row* background.)